# Struggling to combine Storybook + Ant Design. + custom theme

Tags: typescript, webpack, antd, storybook

I'm trying to combine Ant Design with Typescript, Storybook and a custom theme (with Less).

I have a working webpack config for development which looks like this:

```js
import path from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import { CleanWebpackPlugin } from 'clean-webpack-plugin';

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              modules: {
                auto: /\.module\.\w+$/i,
                mode: 'local',
                localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
                javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        test: /\.css$/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

In my src folder I have a folder called styles, containing:

```css
// src/styles/theme.less
@primary-color: green;
```

and

```css
// src/styles/main.less
@import '~antd/lib/style/themes/default.less';
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less'; // Import Ant Design styles by less entry
@import './theme.less'; // variables to override above
```

This works when I run the webpack dev server, - I render a simple Ant Design primary button, and it is green, as expected.

However, when I run Storybook it isn't.

I've tried many different Storybook configs, but preview.js looks like this:

```js
require('../src/styles/main.less');
export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
};
```

Meanwhile my main.js looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.less$/,
      loaders: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'less-loader',
          options: { lessOptions: { javascriptEnabled: true } },
        },
      ],
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

I've tried using the same config as my webpack.development.ts but that doesn't work. A strange thing I've noticed is that the correct theme is being imported, but it's being overwritten by a second import, which is the default theme. I can't understand why...
[image: default theme showing][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZUpl.png) [image: default theme showing][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIoYd.png)

If anyone could help me understand how I can configure Storybook to use the custom theme I'd really appreciate it. I've been working on this for about two days now, I'm not sure how I can fix it. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I just found your question, because I encountered the same issue and I was looking for answers.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any answers to this weird issue.

After working on it for hours, I figured out the issue, so I'm gonna share it.

It's all because of the `.babelrc.js` file.

Mine was like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [["next/babel"]],
  plugins: [["import", { libraryName: "antd", style: true }]],
};
```

I had to go to the `.storybook` directory, create a new `.babelrc.js` file there, and then add this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [["next/babel"]],
  plugins: [["import", { libraryName: "antd", css: true }]],
};
```

I just had to replace `style` with `css`. I'm not sure if this is the right approach, but it did solve my issue completely.

Comment: Nice! I have to admit, I eventually gave up. I restarted the same project with Mantine and Redwood and am enjoying myself, but very awesome that you found this solution, since AntD is pretty cool.